# Grep exclude wildcards not working

Tags: command-line, grep, regex, wildcards

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I am playing around with grep and I hit an issue piping grep to ls.
All examples are limited to a current directory, non-recursive.

If I want to list all files containing a digit in their name:

```
ls | grep [0-9]
```

If I want to list all files containing "d", "h", "m" as a first letter:

```
ls | grep ^[dhm]
```

If I want to list all files containing a digit as their first letter:

```
ls | grep ^[0-9]
```

However, when I try to use `!` inside `[]`, the `!` is not included:

```
user@host:~$ ls | grep [0-9]
1.log
2.log
3.log
hs_err_pid4015.log
Untitled 1.odt
v1.odt

user@host:~$ ls | grep [!0-9]
1.log
2.log
3.log
hs_err_pid4015.log
Untitled 1.odt
v1.odt
```

The same implies if I try to use it with `^`

```
user@host:~$ ls | grep ^[0-9]
1.log
2.log
3.log

user@host:~$ ls | grep ^[!0-9]
1.log
2.log
3.log
```

I have spent several days reading other posts, man pages, articles etc regarding grep and wildcards, but I can't figure it out.
I have tried putting them in `'` and `"`, combining both wildcards flags (`^` and `!`) in `[[]]` etc.

Nothing shows different output that the examples above.

Please, don't show me the solution. 
Explain my mistakes and let me figure it out on my own.

Comment: `grep` uses regular expressions, not wildcards - that's the first thing you should know. Second, always quote your expressions - **the shell** uses wildcards and your expression could be expanded by the shell if it fits something. For example, `[!0-9]` is a shell expression meaning any file with a single character name that isn't a digit. So, if you had a file named `d`, `ls | grep [!0-9]` would actually be `ls | grep d`. So do: `ls | grep '[!0-9]'`. (Of course, considering heemayl's answer.)

Answer (score 5):

The Regex token inside character class for negation is `^`, not `!`.

So you need:

```
ls | grep '^[^0-9]'
```

If you do `ls | grep ^[!0-9]`, then within `[]`, `!` is treated literally and `0-9` is expanded in the usual manner.

Also for this kind of trivial tasks, use shell globbing, Regex is a bit too much for these, and also don't parse `ls`; you could simply do:

```
ls [^[:digit:]]*
ls [![:digit:]]*
```

Note that, `bash` supports both `^`, and `!` as pattern negation token inside character class while globbing.

If you don't want to depend on you `locale`:

```
ls [^[0-9]]*
ls [![0-9]]*
```

Comment: I read that in here: <br/>
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm
<br/> But I never assumed it will need two  ^s.

However, it worked, thank you :)

Comment: @IliyanStankov No problem. Just remember shell globbing and Regex are two different entities. I suggest you to have a go through these two to get a better understanding.